# Interfaces and Classes between Projects

Tags: c#, interface

My application's structure looks like this:

Solution: MySolution

Projects in MySolution: Host, Business, Server.

References between the projects looks like this:
Host <-- Business --> Server
(Business references Host and Server but Host does not reference Server and vice versa because this causes a circular-)

SO, I have some Database stuff in Server.

- There I have a property: DBConenctionString - Which should contain the connection string.
- What I want to do is to set this property from Host.
- I am also keeping all the methods that has anything to do with the database, in the Server project.

Keeping interfaces in mind - so that I can also at a later stage just create a online application(web).

I have some code and its working but I don't know it this is the right way.
If someone can just show me something or point me in the right direction?

CODE:
I have this interface in Library (connection between the other two projects):

```
    public interface IDBUtils
    {
        string DBConnectionString { get; set; }

        bool OpenConnection();

        bool CloseConnection();

        bool ExecuteSQL(string sql);

        bool CreateDatabase(string servername, string databaseName, string databaseDataPath);

        bool CreateDatabaseUser(string servername, string username, string password);
    }
```

Then the class in Library that has the code for the interface:

```
public string DBConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return DBService.DB.DBUtils.DBConnectionString;
    }
    set
    {
        DBService.DB.DBUtils.DBConnectionString = value;
    }
}

public bool OpenConnection()
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.OpenConnection();
}

public bool CloseConnection()
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.CloseConnection();
}

public bool ExecuteSQL(string sql)
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.ExecuteSQL(sql);
}

public bool CreateDatabase(string servername, string databaseName, string databaseDataPath)
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.CreateDatabase(servername, databaseName, databaseDataPath);
}

public bool CreateDatabaseUser(string servername, string username, string password)
{
    return DBService.DB.DBUtils.CreateDatabaseUser(servername, username, password);
}
```

I'm only going to show the property and one method on the server otherwise this is going to get too long.

On the Server:
Property:

```
public static string DBConnectionString { get; set; }
```

The OpenCOnnection() Method:

```
        public static bool OpenConnection()
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                if (DBConnectionString.Length > 0)
                {
                    conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionString);
                    conn.Open();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            catch { /* Do nothing... */ }
            return success;
        }
```

=========================================================================================

To set the property from Host on Server:
It uses the interface on Library:

```
iDBUtils.DBConnectionString = connectionString.ToString();
```

To execute a method from Host on Server:

```
iDBUtils.OpenConnection();
```

So as you can see, Library is the "Middle Man".

Comment: Right, what is problem here. This is simple and good approach

Comment: Maybe you want to try [_codereview_](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I just want to know if this is good or if there are a better way of doing this?